# How to query hops using PGQL?

Tags: oracle-graph

We are trying to write PGQL query to get multiple hop(s) for selected node.

To get nodes and edge for the selected node,
`SELECT n0.id as n0id, e0.id as e0id, n1.id as n1id FROM MATCH (n0)->[e0]->(n1) WHERE n0.id=12345`

To increase nodes and edges result, example 2 hops,
`... FROM MATCH (n0)->[e0]->(n1)->[e1]->(n3) ...`
However in this case, nodes with 1 hop will not be return.

I wonder if there is any way query required hop(s) for selected node?

Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for the PGQL syntax for variable-length paths:

https://pgql-lang.org/spec/1.4/#variable-length-paths

Among these patterns, I suppose the reachability syntax is useful in your case.

```
SELECT n0.id as n0id, e0.id as e0id, n1.id as n1id
FROM MATCH (n0)->/:edge-label{1,3}/->(n1)
WHERE n0.id=12345
```

https://pgql-lang.org/spec/1.4/#between-n-and-m

Thanks!